# How to post Arabic characters in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, utf-8, arabic

Okay,

So I am writing an OpenCart extension that must allow Arabic characters when posting data.

Whenever I post مرحبا the `print_r($_POST)` returns with this: u0645u0631u062du0628u0627

I check the HTML header and it has this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

I checked the PHP file that triggers all SQL queries and it has this code:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $this->link);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $this->link);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8", $this->link);
```

This is in my form tag:

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

I can't think of what else I am doing wrong. The rest of the OpenCart framework supports UTF8 and arabic characters. It is just in this instance where I can't post anything arabic?

Could someone please help me?

Many Thanks

Peter

Comment: Is there a `json_encode` going on in somewhere?

Comment: There is, however the print_r($_POST); is before the json_encode

Comment: Can you `print_r($_POST)` at the earliest point of your app? (Probably at the top of index.php)

Comment: Can you check http-headers that it's not sending different document encoding in the header.
Also meta-tag I would say should be:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: Okay, I done a print_r($_POST); at the very top of the index.php file and I am still getting the same.  How do I check the http-headers?

Comment: I can confirm that  mb_detect_encoding($_POST) results with ASCII if that helps

Comment: @Esailija you were right. it was a JSON related error. I have started using serialize instead now. If you post that as an answer then I will accept :)  Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a a `json_encode` going on in somewhere, start by doing a `print_r($_POST)` at the earliest point of your app (at the top of index.php/your bootstrap file). If it's not showing `uxxxx` then you know it's being done somewhere in between on the `$_POST` data